# Conditional IF inside an IF statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to run multiple queries to insert records into different tables. I have multiple SQL queries:

```
$user_query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user...
$user_settings_query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user_settings...
$user_details_query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user_details...
```

Then I have an IF statement:

```
if($user_query->execute() && $user_settings_query->execute() && $user_details_query->execute) {
    $pdo->commit();
}
```

I am getting this data from a single form and some fields are array values retrieved from checkboxes:

```
settings[] = 'xyz';
```

I have everything working and the queries execute and commit to the DB however if any of the arrays are empty it just writes an empty value to the tables. For example, settings and details only have a single column (JSON) but I don't want that query to execute if the arrays are empty.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
IF($user_query->execute() && IF(!empty($user_settings_array)?$user_settings_query->execute():'') ... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `? :` operator from your example is it.  Be careful: The precedence is unusual in PHP.  It may be best to fully parenthesize the expression.

Other options include `&&` and `||`.  For instance:

```
if ($user_query->execute() && (empty($user_settings_array) || $user_settings_query->execute()) ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the "if", and put execute inside if statment

```
if(!empty($user_settings_array) && $user_query->execute() && $user_settings_query->execute()){
    $pdo->commit();
}
```

Comment: This won't work because I want to execute all the other queries regardless of the empty condition.

Comment: How bout that??